# How to create captions for responsive images in its corners in gallery?

Tags: html, css

I've made gallery on bootstrap and set every `img` `width` from `20%` to `98%` according to screen width. I'm trying to put captions in every `img` in gallery in its right bottom corner.

```
<div id="galery">
  <a href="URL" class="GaleryItem"><img src="URL"></a>
  <a href="URL" class="GaleryItem"><img src="URL"></a>
  <a href="URL" class="GaleryItem"><img src="URL"></a>
  .
  .
  .
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#galery{
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1653px){
    a.GaleryItem>img{
        width:20%;
        height:auto;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 586px){
    a.GaleryItem>img{
        width:98%;
    }
}
```

How to make caption that is always in `img` corner whenever it changes its size with screen width?

I have tried this:

```
<div id="galery">
  <a href="/domy-galeria.php?active=1" class="GaleryItem" target="_blank">
    <img src="/img/mini/01min600.jpg" alt="domek nr1">
    <div class="nr-domku">01</div>
    .
    .
    .
  </a>
</div>
```

with this css:

```
.nr-domku{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -82px;
    right: 7px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    padding: 3px 9px 2px 15px;
    border-radius: 25px 0 25px 0;
}
```

Comment: where is the caption in your code?

Comment: The question is "How to ..." so im waiting for your ideas.

Comment: this is not a code service site. what have you tried so far?

Comment: what are the caption to be filled with/from ? your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your image, or simply use your href as a wrap, then position your caption with absolute, bottom: 0, and right: 0, text-align: right.

.wrap{

}

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#galery{
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
#galery .wrap{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#galery img{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 }
#galery .caption{
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
  background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.8);
}
#galery .wrap p{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #1d1d1d;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="galery">
  <a href="URL" class="GaleryItem">
    <div class="wrap">
      <img src="http://cdn.klubplus.com/pictures/images/000/000/802/original/628494-zmaizing-lake-bled-in-slovenia.jpg">
      <p class="caption">Something in bottom right.</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Keep in mind there is many options, sky is the limit, it all depends how creative you are! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your image in a `div` or `figure`, set this wrapper as `position: relative`, and insert a sibling text to your `image` with `position:absolute`, like in the example:
https://jsfiddle.net/wv8v3f9g/

```css
figure {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

figcaption.cap-rb {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="//placehold.it/150x100" />
  <figcaption class="cap-rb">Wow, a caption</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
  <img src="//placehold.it/200x100" />
  <figcaption class="cap-rb">Wow, a caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```